# When setting Sorting in code, the ColumnHeader's arrow doesn't point to any direction

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

When adding the sortings to A ListCollectionView in the code like this:

```
RowViewModelsView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("FilterOrder", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

It will work fine. However the actual arrow on the column Header doesn't point to any direction.  This only works if I actually click on the column header myself (and hence sort again).

I think I have to raise a notification, but have no idea where to get the arrows shown.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Grid.Columns(indexColumn).HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you mean I should set the SortGlyphDirection myself when setting the sorting in the code? And do I have to do this in the View's code behind directly on the dataGrid?, it seems I couldn't do it from the ViewModel correct?

Comment: You must order your control as well said in your question and after ordination glyph set the header cell belonging to the column being sorted

Comment: In WPF I'm not sure because I've been using Windows Forms DataGridView Controls.